# Is there any apis for searching and downloading subtitles online?

Tags: api, subtitle

I need an api for searching and downloading subtitles online in my android app.

I tried the Sublight's api,but i can't get any subtitle.

Is there any other api for that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, actually. [OpenSubtitles.org](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en) has a nice API for searching and downloading.

[Here you go](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC)

Comment: It's weird they didn't make a REST API.

Comment: They now have a REST API. https://forum.opensubtitles.org/viewtopic.php?t=16453

Comment: True! Here the documentation for their REST API: https://opensubtitles.stoplight.io/docs/opensubtitles-api/open_api.json